# Promises vs function calls/setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, promise, callstack

What is the difference between these scenarios when it comes to the call stack?

scenario 1:

```
function A(){//doStuff};
function B(){//doStuff};
```

scenario 2:

```
function A(){//doStuff};
window.setTimeOut(function B(){//doStuff}, 5000);
```

scenario 3:

```
function A(){//doStuff}.then(function B(){//doStuff});
```

I was discussing a bug with someone and, they suggested that I just add a setTimeOut to the second function and wait to see if it fires. I am using a promise A+ library and I am wondering if it is possible to just attach a promise to the first function and fire the second one when function A is done.

Also I am not sure what the main difference of the setTimeOut and the promise would be vs the first scenario. I know that promises and timeouts move functions to the end of the call stack but I'm not sure what happens past that point and how that would be different than scenario 1. Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if it is possible to just attach a promise to the first function and fire the second one when function A is done.

Promises work by hooking on the return values of functions. A function returns a promise which in turn you can hook on. JavaScript does not expose any way to detect when a function has finished executing. So for example if you have an API that does:

```
api.someAsyncThing(); // does not return a promise
```

There is no way to know when the function finished running unless it exposes a side effect in which case you can poll inside a setInterval and create a promise - that's very hacky though.

> Also I am not sure what the main difference of the setTimeOut and the promise would be vs the first scenario.

`setTimeout` introduces a timeout, it's quite possible that A will not finish within the timeout and B will start running before A is finished with nested callbacks. The only difference is that it *might* wait long enough - this is called a [race-condition](/questions/tagged/race-condition).

Comment: how can B "start running before A is finished" if JS is single-threaded?

Comment: @dandavis For example `function A(){ setTimeout(function(){ alert("HI"); }, 6000); }` the function has returned but it will cause side effects for 6 seconds longer.

Comment: Can I call a promise on a function that returns a value? Even if it just returns true for example.

Comment: You can `Promise.resolve` the return value but that's probably not what you want. Promises are meant for value + time cases where things are asynchronous.

Comment: About what @dandavis asked. A functions side effects can persist for longer than the function itself? 

Also does javascript have anyway to check when something has finished executing?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a way to know when something is done - this is where promises kick in

Answer (score 0):

**Timeouts** and **Promises** both serve to execute code in an asynchronous way but with differences characteristics and purposes:

**setTimeout** 
-   Delays the execution of a function by specific time duration.
-   Does not block the rest of the code execution (asynchronous behavior)
-   They create Macrotask (browser internal operation)

**Promises** 
-   They are a wrapper to allow asynchronous execution of code(Eg: an ajax call). (Does not depend on specific time duration)
-   They are especially useful for changing differents async calls.
-   Does not block the rest of the code execution (asynchronous behavior) at less you are using the await operator.
-   They create *Microtask* (browser internal operation), which have priority over the *Macrotask*.

Recommendation

- Use **setTimeout** when you want to delay a function execution some specific time duration and not block the rest of the code execution in the process
- Use **Promises**:
  When you want to execute some async code and to avoid the “callback hell” (yes because you can make asynchronous ajax calls without Promises but the syntax is less clear and more prone to errors)